# View child not working with *ngIf ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 with animations.

I installed

```
npm install --save CSS-animator
```

Here is my Template

```
<div class="alert" *ngIf="!show" #myElement> 
  <h5>Here is my animation</h5>
</div>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-row ion-button class="btn-full" *ngIf="show">
    <ion-col text-left (click)="nav()">
        Checkout   <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col text-right>
        <img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee">4200
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

I declare variable and the name is show also import view child

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimationService, AnimationBuilder } from 'css-animator';

export class CartPage {

    show: boolean = true;
    private animator: AnimationBuilder;
    @ViewChild('myElement') myElem;

    constructor(
      animationService: AnimationService, 
      public navCtrl: NavController, 
      public navParams: NavParams
    ) {
        this.animator = animationService.builder();
    }

    nav() {
        var i = document.querySelector('alert');
        this.show = false;
        this.animator.setType('bounce').show(this.myElem.nativeElement);
    }

}
```

I am getting this error.

```
Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

How can i fix this issue.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `*ngIf` the HTML is not rendered if the condition is not met, so when you set `show` to true `myElement` is not rendered. You should use `hidden` instead of `ngIf` so that element is rendered but it's `display` property is set to `none` using css, that way you can access `myElement` even when it is not shown like below:

```
<div class="alert" [hidden]="show" #myElement> 
  <h5>Here is my animation</h5>
</div>
```